# Simple href angular ionic not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is a simple `href`, which is not working in Angular with ionic. No console errors.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" style="text-align:center">           
  <a class="button button-outline button-positive" href="#/app/nutrition" style="width:300px;">
     SUBMIT
  </a>
</label>
```

Comment: you can make ui-sref to the state name directly

Comment: Can you post config block of your application where routes are defined?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this using `button` instead of `a`:

```
$state.go("app.formulareport");
```

Called the above line in `ng-click` attached to the `button`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

`href="#/app/nutrition"`

use:

```
href="app/nutrition"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<a>` element with `<button>` and this should work.

Sometimes, there's a problem with `<label>` element that should be changed to `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ui-sref in place of href.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" style="text-align:center">           
      <a class="button button-outline button-positive" ui-sref="app.nutrition" style="width:300px;">SUBMIT 
      </a>
</label>
```